# PHP socket_connect() doesn't connect to local IP

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to work with teamspeak on my pc, but because of simplicity I wanna use my raspberry PI to execute the script, so I'm just writing my script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = "192.168.2.11";
$service_port = 25639;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if($socket === false)
{
    die("Error: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."\n");
}
echo "Connecting to {$address}:{$service_port}...\n";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if($result === false)
{
    die("Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\n");
}
echo socket_read($socket, 512);
?>
```

But everytime I run it, it just gives me:

> Connecting to 192.168.2.11:25639...

and no further messages. I am thinking the error is at `socket_create`, but changing the parameters just throws errors.

I googled and searched on stack, but it looks like I'm the only one that has this issue. :/

Comment: Are you trying to run this as a client or server?

Comment: @MatthijsOtterloo Client that connects to the teamspeak telnet thing.

Comment: You think PHP is executing its instructions out of sequence? If it has output "Connecting to 192.168.2.11:25639..." then this is *after* socket_create() but immediately before socket_connect() and more code. You might start by adding some output after socket_connect() to confirm that is where the problem lies. If you want to connect to a local ip why not use localhost?

Comment: Try checking your firewall rules

Comment: @ChupakabraHunter I am pretty sure local network bypasses firewall, but I will check.